# Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col7

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange

I need to join two worksheets from different files in another one that already exist in Google Sheets

I tried to do this:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1GoKFiJjBKcGQGGi6JMvk9xD5TIypsNSmpLCTeadWQnU","'BDD PROYECTOS'!A2:AP");IMPORTRANGE("1jiE-8ciu-BzfIxts5Y6d-Yi8gjhgx4dvS4EQMK0Conc","'BDD PROYECTOS'!A3:AP")},"Where Col7 is not null",1)
```

The error that brings is

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col7

What should i do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a "Select" portion to your QUERY, so there is "NO_COLUMN: Col7," because you haven't "Select(ed)" any columns. Try this:

`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1GoKFiJjBKcGQGGi6JMvk9xD5TIypsNSmpLCTeadWQnU","'BDD PROYECTOS'!A2:AP");IMPORTRANGE("1jiE-8ciu-BzfIxts5Y6d-Yi8gjhgx4dvS4EQMK0Conc","'BDD PROYECTOS'!A3:AP")},"Select * Where Col7 Is Not Null",1)`

This now reads "Select [all columns] where column seven is not null."